# jquery cyclic, images wrong place, freemarker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, freemarker

I have problem with images, because they are showing under the conteiner

Screen : http://i61.tinypic.com/117u5tv.png

On the screen it's a white line ( div block) and this image should go inside it and have 10px padding between image and this white box.

My html file:

```
<div class="tmp">
    <#list slide_news_model as newsItem>
        <div class="outer">
           <div class="inner">
             <img width="100%" src="..." alt="" />
           </div>
        </div> 
    </#list>
</div>
```

My css file

```
 .tmp {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.outer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.inner {
    padding: 10px;
    position : relative;
}
.inner img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

My js file

```
  function cycleInit() {
            $('.tmp').cycle( { 
                fx:      '${slide_effect}', 
                speed:    ${slide_speed}, 
                timeout:  ${slide_timeout},
                containerResize: 0,
                slideResize: 0,
                fit:1,
                pause:1
            });
        }
        cycleInit();
 }
```

I tried adding containerResize: 1 and as a result image is inside this white box, but the height of this white box is constant (what is wrong).
I want all images having the same width

Comment: I think `height:100%;` will only work if its parent div is given some specific height. Hence all the children `divs` here have height 0, resulting in a white line. Share a working link so we can understand the problem better.

Comment: but i can't have fixed height. It should change dynamically depending on the height of image.